# How to recursively load classes from a particular package

Tags: java, package

I am creating a modular app. The following is my design:

```
my_app_package  
  PluginsLoader.java  
  plugins_package
    plugin_A  
      Start.java  
      plugin_a_inner_package_1  
      plugin_a_inner_package_2
      plugin_a_inner_package _3  
    plugin_B  
      Start.java  
      plugin_b_inner_package_1  
      plugin_b_inner_package_2  
    plugin_C  
      Start.java  
      plugin_c_inner_package_1
```

I would like to recursively go through all the **`Start.java`** classes in the roots of **plugins_package** root packages, but not go through any of the **pluginA, pluinB etc etc*_inner_package**s.

How can I do this efficiently.

I know **`my_app_package.plugins_package.*.Start.java`** will not work, but it draws on the idea of what I'm seeking.

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

I would like to recursively go through all the Start.java classes in the roots of plugins_package packages, but not go through any of the **pluginA, pluinB** etc etc _inner_packages like **`plugin_a_inner_package_1`**. With Java Reflections, I'll wind up going through everything in the **plugins_package**.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my_app_package.plugins_package");

 Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses =  reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

I would only like to go through the root package of a plugin package, say **plugins_package.plugin_A** then walk out with the the `**Start class**`, then repeat this for all other plugin packages like plugin_B, plugin_C, etc, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "go through"?

Comment: Don’t use reflection.  The [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class is made for this.